# Invoke Metamask with a pure JS/HTML set up

Tags: metamask, signature, frontend

I am new to front end Web3 and I am trying to have a simple SIGN button that will invoke metamask to sign a "Message". I can't seem to get it working. I am using pure HTML/JS without any frameworks such as React etc.

This code:

```
function sign(){
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    console.log(web3.version);
    web3.eth.sign(("dinosaur"), owner, console.log);
}
```

**returns:**

*Error: Returned error: cannot sign data; no private key*

This other attempt:

```
function sign(){

    web3.eth.personal.sign('message to sign', owner)
    .then(signature => {
        // whatever
    });
}
```

**returns:**

*Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: Method personal_sign not supported.*

I am using localhost ganache and metamask in Chrome connecting to ganache and initiating web3 using:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please follow MetaMask instructionsn how to set up a web3 object.

Comment: You reply isn't useful. It doesn't contain any links or instructions

Comment: It is not a reply, it is a comment. MetaMask has a tutorial how to use it and your code looks nothing like it should be.

Comment: Alright I went there and the first line is:

if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
}


This one is turning out false for me. Even though my metamask is installed and I use it daily. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed my issue will answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had is that I was serving the html and js files using the file:// in chrome. Metamask doesn't support as [per here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056623/metamask-web3-is-undefined) that so I had to install the HTTP-server using these steps:

1> Have Node.js installed in your system.

2> In CMD, run the command npm install http-server -g

3> Navigate to the specific path of your file folder in CMD and run the command http-server

4> Go to your browser and type localhost:8080. Your Application should run there.

After this Metamask was coming up